# Ninject base class and inheriting class bind to the same instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a generic repository that takes DbContext as a constructor parameter.  To inject it my binding looks as such:

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<MyApplicationsContext>().InRequestScope();
```

I also have custom repositories, which take MyApplicationContext directly as a constructor parameter.  How do I write a binding as such that regardless whether a repository requests the base class DbContext or the inheriting class MyApplicationContext it gets the same instance InRequestScope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll want to use is an overload of the `Bind<>()` method.

In your case your code would be:

```
Bind<DbContext, MyApplicationsContext>().To<MyApplicationsContext>().InRequestScope();
```

In case you want to use open generics or need to bind using `System.Type` you can use this overload

```
Bind(typeof(DbContext), typeof(MyApplicationsContext))
    .To(typeof(MyApplicationsContext))
    .InRequestScope();
```